# display content depending on which user in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have four differnet data entry users that will be using four different forms on my asp.net application to enter data into a database.

i currently have windows authentication so that the user will not see the other user's form.

my question is how can i send all the four groups the same link http://website....default.aspx and have it display content SPECIFICALLY for that users?

Comment: ed's first bullet is great, but i would like to know how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

- Have your link discover the logged-in user and forward them to a different page.
- Dynamically build the form you want them to see based on the logged-in user.
- *(Warning: don't use this)* Use CSS to hide the form elements you don't want them to see.

Without knowing more about the problem, this is the best answer I can give.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using CSS for this - if someone knows what they're doing, they can just edit the CSS in the DOM and get at things they shouldn't see. The first two options are fine, of course.

Comment: @ed s how would i do this: Have your link discover the logged-in user and forward them to a different page.

Comment: Please remove your CSS recommendation (or else add a strongly-worded disclaimer.) It's borderline-criminal to use CSS to hide secure portions of your site.

Comment: @diev it's an interesting answer for me :) but i would highly prefer the first bullet, do you know how to do it?

Comment: @I__ Essentially provided you have ASP.NET membership set up, you can access the currently logged-in user using something like `MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);`

Comment: @neil i have windows auth not asp.net membership - how do i set it up?

Comment: @Neil and dlev: Thanks for the note about CSS. I left it there for completeness, but you're very right, it's a terrible idea.